# adding new column in dynamo DB using boto3 resource with update_item

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-dynamodb

I need to update a row in Dynomodb while doing so need to include a new column which is already not there.

```
resp = table.update_item(
            Key={
                'Pkey': 'key1',
                'Skey': 'skwy2'
            },
            UpdateExpression='ADD dateModified = :input2, SET IsActive = :input1',
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':input1': False,
                ':input2' :  datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)
            },
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
        )
```

now I need to update IsActive  field to false and insert new dateModified value to that .

getting error as
**Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "=", near: "dateModified = :input2"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD that for the `ADD` operation you don't use `=`

so the correct expression should be `ADD dateModified :input2 SET IsActive = :input1`